# How to measure the network traffic in/out between two virtual networks in azure?

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn, virtual-network

I have deployed two virtual network gateway associated two different virtual networks. I have connected them via two connections (say connect_1 and connect_2).
As soon as I did this, on the azure portal I can see some bytes of data getting in and out.(Data in:202.28 KiB, Data out:202.66 KiB)
How is this possible when i haven`t exchanged any data?

Also, if I exchange data, what will be the parameter to measure the bandwidth? Will it be tunnel_egress_bytes_transferred and tunnel_ingress_bytes_transferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current VPN gateway bandwidth in use, you could check the metric `Gateway S2S Bandwidth` for all connections associated with this gateway.

If you exchange data, you could check [these dimension metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftnetworkvirtualnetworkgateways) with `Tunnel` prefix name for each of VNET to VNET connections in the Virtual network gateway panel. For example, select the metric `TunnelAverageBandwidth` with filtering `ConnectionName` or `RemoteIP`, you will see the specific tunnel bandwidth in bytes per second.

[image]

Additionally, if you just want to connect the two virtual networks in Azure, you could select [VNet peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-connect-virtual-networks-portal). It has simple operation and less cost.